# jQuery cookies not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm setting cookies using [jquery-cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and appending a comma on every entry so it looks like this:

"ee337,ee389,ee347,etc."

I'm doing this like this:

```
if($.cookie('oswfav') == null){
    $.cookie('oswfav', id, {expires: 365});
} else {
    var curCook = $.cookie('oswfav');
    $.cookie('oswfav', curCook+','+id, {expires: 365});
}
```

In Firefox/Chrome, this works fine and they get appended correctly. However in IE, it works the first time (the first ID comes in fine) but adding more to the cookie doesn't work. I've tried setting them with PHP cookies too and got the same result.

Is there something I'm missing/need to set for IE to work?

Comment: I think IE uses comma's in cookies to seperate them. Try using a different seperator. I had the same problem a few days ago and fixed it by using a _dot_ instead.

Comment: That never occurred to me, I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if it will solve your pbm but give a try to this, use `;` as separator.

I am also re-writing your code in a little different way

```
if($.cookie('oswfav')){
    var newCook = $.cookie('oswfav') + ';' + id;
    $.cookie('oswfav', newCook, {expires: 365});
} else {
    $.cookie('oswfav', id, {expires: 365});
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I used a dot instead of a semi-colon. Thanks anyways :)